# nested form in MVC5

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a page with several blocks. I have, in that order :
- a name block with others informations
- a multi-comments block
- an address block

User should have possibility to add a comment with a button in the multi-comments block, and save all others data (name and address) from others blocks with a button at the bottom of the page.

So, multi-comments block is a form, nested in a form for the whole page. It won't work. Do you have an idea to help me, without change the user interface ?

Comment: Nested forms are invalid html and not supported

Comment: that's why I said it won't work. But users need that UI, what could I do for them ?

Comment: why don't you combine all elements inside one form and try to submit the data that are valid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use 2 different actions on the same form with the "formaction" attribute on input element !

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajouter un commentaire" formaction=@Url.Action("AddHotlinerComment") formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Appliquer les modifications" formaction=@Url.Action("Update") formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

So, it is solved :)